# Example of countably additive function from a Boolean algebra to [0,infinity] that is not finitely additive

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, outer-measure

This example is implied to exist by Tao’s undergrad measure theory text, exercise 1.7.4, with the claim that further assuming that the empty set getting mapped to 0 prevents such a function from existing. As far as I can tell, padding out the countable union with empty sets forces any other set to be mapped to infinity if the image of the empty set is nonzero (and thus infinite). But the constant infinity map is finitely additive, right? What am I missing here?

Comment: What are the exact definitions of "countably additive" and "finitely additive"?

Comment: On my phone now so I mean that the function maps disjoint unions to sums.

Comment: Either finite or Countably additive respectively.

Comment: I'm not asking what the definition is roughly, but what it is _exactly_.  I'm guessing the answer to your question has to do with some subtlety in the precise definitions Tao uses.

Comment: Ok I will have to wait until I am at a computer.

Comment: If $f(\phi)>0$, $f(A)\geq 0$ for all $A$ in the algebra, and $f$ is countably additive, then $$f(A) = f(A \cup \cup_{i=1}^{\infty}\phi) = f(A) + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f(\phi) = \infty \quad \forall A$$ and so $f(A)=\infty$ for all $A$ in the algebra (including $\phi$ itself). Here I assume "countably additive" means that if $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is a countably infinite sequence of disjoint sets in the algebra then $f(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f(A_i)$.

Comment: In retrospect, the argument I give above may be what you are describing in your question itself.  When I first read that, I didn't get what you were talking about.  I noticed you  mentioned mapping the empty set to a positive number so I decided to give that idea some precision in my above comment, the conclusion is just that everything gets mapped to $\infty$. So, yes I agree that if $f(A)=\infty$ for all $A$ then that is "finitely additive."

Comment: What does 1.7.4 ask for **exactly**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That book is online:

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwj_yb6Xlo_hAhWT51QKHU1YAHIQFjABegQIBBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fterrytao.files.wordpress.com%2F2012%2F12%2Fgsm-126-tao5-measure-book.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0GnO1oyFyno__7TnnfBVCl

The Exercise 1.7.4 does *not* imply existence of function that is countably additive but not finitely additive. Eric's comment on the precise definition of *finitely additive* is the key here.

#### Finitely additive

Definition 1.4.19 gives: With $\mathcal{B}$ a Boolean algebra, a map $\mu:\mathcal{B}\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ is *finitely additive* if

(Axiom 1) $\mu(\phi)=0$.

(Axiom 2) $\mu(A \cup B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B)$ whenever $A, B$ are disjoint and in $\mathcal{B}$.

#### Countably additive

The defintion of *countably additive* (Definition 1.4.27) keeps Axiom 1 but changes Axiom 2 to treat countable unions of disjoint sets (it also assumes $\mathcal{B}$ is a sigma-algebra rather than an algebra).

#### Exercise 1.7.4a

The exercise 1.7.4a just wants you to show that if $\mathcal{B}$ is a Boolean algebra and if $\mu:\mathcal{B} \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ a function, then $\mu$ is finitely additive whenever the following two properties hold:

(i) $\mu(\phi)=0$.

(ii)  $\mu(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i)= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_i)$ whenever $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are disjoint sets in the Boolean algebra such that $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$ is also in the Boolean algebra.

That exercise was not trying to imagine a scenario where  $\mu(\phi)>0$ (that would not fit the definition of either *finitely additive* or *countably additive*).

Comment: Exercise 1.7.4. is not in that linked text. What is its statement exactly?

Comment: It is there on page 185.

Comment: Thank you Michael—this matches the rest of the exercise as well.